# While deploy chat bot on Azure , Auto Welcome Message doesn't work?

Tags: azure, deployment, frameworks, botframework, chatbot

In Bot Simulator work's perfect

but While Deployemnt ,then we testing this function , Auto Initiate Welcome Message doesn't work  .
Checkout Below Screenshot for details  .

Give me help please !1 I am stuck this problem
Contact Personally : +91 9786252624
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZWcY.png

Comment: Take a look at this GitHub comment regarding [Web Chat Welcome Messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2120#issuecomment-516056614).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed the condition on member.id check to === instead of !== and that fixed it for me for both emulator and webchat. One of my bots runs in Teams in addition to these channels, and it does NOT give me the welcome message in that case, which I what I want and expect. Here is the code from my bot.js file.

```js
        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;

            for (let member of membersAdded) {
                if (member.id === context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    await context.sendActivity(welcomeMessage);
                }
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
```

Comment: its works perfect . you are saving my time .thanks buddy!!